# Running a single JUnit test in Eclipse will not do anything

Tags: eclipse, testing, junit

When i try to run one method in my junt test from Eclipse it will not run. Either right click on a junit test method or from the context menu or clicking F11 when the test is selected will not work. It clears out previous run test and then nothing happens. My tests are simple normal test (without any params).

When i run all test nothing they run fine.

I removed the project and did a mvn clean install eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse and reimported the project but no difference.

Eclipse version is: Oxygen Release (4.7.0) (but this problem has been here from a long time)

Any clue?

i just now see an error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runner.Description.getClassName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.DescriptionMatcher$LeadingIdentifierMatcher.matches(DescriptionMatcher.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.DescriptionMatcher$CompositeMatcher.matches(DescriptionMatcher.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.SubForestFilter.collectIncludedDescriptions(SubForestFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.SubForestFilter.apply(SubForestFilter.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Comment: 'right click on a junit test method': This hopefully does not run a unit test! ;) You should describe in more detail what you are doing and maybe post the code of one of the not running unit tests.

Comment: Small remark: mvn eclipse:eclipse is now for over 2 years retired and unsupported and shouldn't be used any more

Comment: all tests work but only when i run them all (the whole class in one run). when i run one method of the test class then it failed. but i found an answer, see below. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i upgraded the versions of junit and the problem is gone now :)

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit-dep -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```